# Validating a complex object in Flask

Tags: python, flask

```
def validateWord(classObject):
    if (hasattr('classObject', 'students') and 0 < len(classObject["students"])):
        studentObject = classObject["students"][0]
    else:
        return False


    if ("id" in classObject and "name" in classObject and "id" in studentObject and "fName" in studentObject and "lName" in studentObject):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I have an object class and it has an object named students inside of it. There's a one-to-many relationship between the two object and I need to validate that complex object whenever the user make a POST request. The issue is that I have a complex object and the validation I wrote would only work if I only have 1 student per class. How do you write a validation function that checks every student instead of just checking the first?

I am using Flask. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the type of * classObject*? Is it a `dict`-like object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check `"id" in studentObject and "fName" in studentObject and "lName" in studentObject` for all students, you can use the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function.

For instance:

```py
def validateWord(classObject):
    if "students" in classObject:
        students = classObject["students"]
        return (
            "id" in classObject
            and "name" in classObject
            and all("id" in student and "fName" in student and "lName" in student
                    for student in students)
        )
    else:
        return False
```

Note: I think you need to write `hasattr(classObject, "students")` instead of `hasattr("classObject", "students")` or may be it is `"students" in classObject`.